# WordPress - Query specific category and automatically change category each month

Tags: php, jquery

I want to create a carousel slideshow that pulls posts from a specific Category ID and then have the Category ID automatically change each month and replace the posts with the posts from the new month's Category ID.

Eg:

March - only display posts from Category ID = 42

April - only display posts from Category ID = 12

May - only display posts from Category ID = 37

Answer (score 0):

Natively, I would suggest you to create an option page with some options value.

Take a look at this : https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-settings-options-page-for-wordpress-plugin/

After created your options, do you logic by getting the options value (= category id) per key (= month number)

Some plugin does that easily (such as ACF, but premium version)